# What does it mean to have geknipt payos?

Tags: minhag, yiddish, payot-sideburns

What does it mean to have geknipt payos? Is this a specific length or style? Who would have the minhag of keeping their payos as whatever geknipt means?

Comment: Where have you heard the term?

Comment: shidduch website. one of the questions was what style payos do you have and there was a drop down menu for options

Comment: I think it means trimmed/snipped. As in not let grow out long (i.e. the opposite of [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_IC1swogp6gc/TTSAFqRCV2I/AAAAAAAAGFY/82MCOzv0zog/s1600/366726.jpg)).

Comment: @Yishai is that a guess?

Comment: Actually I think it means crimped or curled, from yiddish 'knaypn'

Comment: FWIW, I don't think that this question is off-topic, because even though it's based in Yiddish, it asks about a Jewish/mitzvah practice.

Comment: @Shokhet I second the movement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means curled/twisted up and stuck behind your ears. I have geknipte peyos.

Comment: Improve your answer by answering the second question -- who (what groups) have this custom.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Care to [edit] and tell us how you know?  ("I speak Yiddish fluently and that's what it means" would be an acceptable start)