# Why are there so many different types of payos that Jews grow?

Tags: provenance, payot-sideburns

I would like to know how the different minhagim regarding growing payos  (sidelocks) developed. I see so many different styles including curled, straight, tucked behind the ear, twisted above the ear, sideburns, wild growth etc. Can each of these styles be traced back to certain countries of origin? Are there any styles that trace back to the early days of Jewish history?

Comment: "Why are there so many types of shoes that Jews wear?" seems like an equally interesting question. We all know people have different styles and various aesthetics go in and out of style.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Great. So you're saying that it's just a matter of styles like shoes and eyeglasses. That's what I was asking. Why don't you post that as the answer?

Comment: @MarkA. Because if he is right, then it would be nearly impossible to prove, as Jewish literature gives very little screen time to irrelevant historical fashion decisions.

Comment: 2 shitot if peot can be bellow the hairs area,  arizal & Rashash

Comment: Related questions on the meaning and origins of [arup peyos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/what-does-it-mean-to-have-arup-payos?rq=1), [geknipt payos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/what-does-it-mean-to-have-geknipt-payos?rq=1), [short Lubavitch peyos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/why-is-the-lubavitch-custom-to-have-short-peoth?rq=1) and [Teimani simanim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36101/what-is-the-history-of-teimani-peyos?rq=1)

Comment: @mevaqesh. So it's just a question of style? Exactly like shoes and glasses? No other significance in the different minhagim? I imagine somebody out there has some better info than that.

Comment: This is too massive of a question. There are so many payos styles to count and trace back to a specific place! Not to mention there are different ways people interpret the part in the Torah referring to not shaving the edges of the beard...

Comment: @Ezra. Nothing is too massive for the Miyodeya family. Anyways, it's not that many basic options. Long curled, long straight, behind the ears, twisted above the ears, pulled up under the yarmulkah.

Comment: @MarkA. Your comment does not seem to be a response to what I said. Since you raise issue, however, I would respond: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia.

Comment: `Nothing is too massive for the Miyodeya family` While a romantic notion, that is simply false. `too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.`

Comment: @Mark A. - ...Some people curl the payos 13 times, others do not, some don't even have defined payos at all, some grow them long but tuck them behind the ears still...The options are endless

Comment: Note that Rambam writes that there is no reason to grow out one's peyot as is commonly assumed.